# Derivative of trace of functions of $X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to find the derivative of the following function?

$$\mbox{tr} \left( X'A' \left(B + X'CX + DX + X'D'\right)^{-1}AX \right)$$

I thought to write it using colon notation, but the quantities and not separable.

Comment: Have you tried using differentials?

Comment: @Dunkel I am trying to solve it.  Can I apply the product rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define some additional matrices to hide the complexity that will occur when terms are expanded.
$$\eqalign{
P &= B + X^TCX + DX + X^TD^T \cr
Q &= AX \cr
R &= P^{-T}QQ^TP^{-T} \cr
S &= P^{-1}+P^{-T} \cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables.
Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= {\rm Tr}\big(P^{-1}QQ^T\big)
 \,\,=\,\, P^{-1}:QQ^T
 \,\,=\,\, QQ^T:P^{-1} \cr
d\phi
 &= P^{-1}:2\,{\rm sym}(dQ\,Q^T) + QQ^T:dP^{-1} \cr
 &= (P^{-1}+P^{-T}):dQ\,Q^T - QQ^T:(P^{-1}\,dP\,P^{-1}) \cr
 &= SQ:dQ - R:dP \cr
 &= SQ:A\,dX - R:\big(dX^TCX+dX^TD^T+X^TC\,dX+D\,dX\big) \cr
 &= A^TSQ:dX - R(CX+D^T)^T:dX^T - (X^TC+D)^TR:dX \cr
 &= A^TSQ:dX - (CX+D^T)R^T:dX - (C^TX+D^T)R:dX \cr
 &= \Big(A^TSQ - (CX+D^T)R^T - (C^TX+D^T)R\Big):dX \cr
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
 &= A^TSQ - (CX+D^T)R^T - (C^TX+D^T)R \cr
}$$
where the function $\,{\rm sym}(X) = \tfrac{1}{2}(X+X^T)$

and the trace product is $\,A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Comment: Thank you very much greg!

Comment: @shani, accept greg's answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Dunkel. You must accept greg's hard work...

Answer (score 1):

User greg already provided you with an answer, I just want to point you to this new online tool: http://www.matrixcalculus.org/ simply enter `tr(X' * A' * inv(B + X'*C*X + D*X +X'*D')*A*X)`

Comment: @Hypeplane Thanks, it is very useful.